# C++ HTML viewer for scanning?

Tags: c++, html

I just need some help in pointing me in the right direction. I have no issue with research but I don't know where to start!!! I want to make a program that uses a websites search function, but doesn't display the page. It will save the page and scan the HTML for a specific string and display it.

Would it work better to display the page in the background and search it, this way I don't have to save anything??

Where do I start??

Comment: You can search a page without "saving" it by downloading it into memory, rather than to your hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

A web page is mostly simple text. You can download a page with [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and search it pretty much like you would any other text. If you don't want to search the contents of the tags, you'd want to [search after parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2602332/179910).